# For $A$ positive semidefinite and $\theta_1 ^{T} \theta_2 = 0$ is it true that $\theta_1^{T} A \theta_1 + 2 \theta_1^{T} A \theta_2 \geq 0$?

Tags: matrices, inequality, optimization, quadratic-forms

I have been trying to prove or disprove that for $\theta_1, \theta_2 \in \mathbb{R}^P$ such that $\theta_1 ^{T} \theta_2 = 0$ we have the following inequality

> $$\theta_1^{T} A \theta_1 + 2 \theta_1^{T} A \theta_2 \geq 0, $$

for some positive semidefinite matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$. I have been experimenting with the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality and its variants but I haven't been able to prove the assertion. This makes me believe that the claim is false but I don't have any counterexamples at hand. Could I please then get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true if both vectors are orthogonal eigenvectors, then $v_1^TAv_2 = \lambda v_1^Tv_2=0$.

Here is a counterexample: Let
$$
A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&0}, v = \pmatrix{1\\1}, w = \pmatrix{-1\\1} 
$$
then
$$
0=(v+w)^TA(v+w) = v^TAv + 2 v^TAw + w^Tw,
$$
since $w\ne 0$, it follows $v^TAv + 2 v^TAw<0$.

Comment: I think you missed an "if" in your first sentence. Could you also clarify that a bit? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: in this case the mixed term $v_1^TAv_2$ is zero.

Comment: Is there any other condition that will make this inequality true, you think?